# Angularjs get filtered entries

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with a filter. The table entries (rows) have a checkbox. I'd like to select all the filtered entries checkboxes. How can I get them?

So far I can select all items of the table:

Table checkbox:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-change="checkBoxChanged(box)" ng-checked="selectedFileIds.indexOf(content._id) > -1"/></td>
```

I put a selectedItem-array to the scope, that is compared in the "checked"-section of the table element.

What I don't know is, how to get the filtered entries that are displayed.

Edit:

This is where I'm filtering my table:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="box in boxList | filter:searchText" ng-dblclick="openBox(box._id)">
```

the model for the search is this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

Comment: What do you mean by a filter? are you filtering yor model in the controller? if not, you should consider creating a method for filtering/selecting your data model in the controller - because that's where your data lives.

Comment: I added the filter-method to the post

Comment: without knowing how your controller looks, it's hard to tell you anything. my approach would be to put a `checked` property on each object called `box`. thus you'll be able to differentiate between single boxes. now to check a portion of the boxes, i would first reset all boxes, then re-check the boxes that meet the filter criteria.

Comment: I don't use a controller to filter items. It's just the basic angular filter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change model for checkbox to

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="box.checked" />
```

and after that you can filter by checked property of boxes.

Comment: Do I have to add this attribute to my box-model?
I just wrote my own filter to handle this problem.

Comment: You may set it, but it's not necessary, because you need only selected boxes, and you'll be selecting them by [ng-true-value](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) that will be set by angular on check (default state will be unchecked). If you need select checks on base of initial state you need to use [ngChecked](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked).

Comment: thx, that works too. I'll keep my own filter though, so I have more options for further requirements.